# What am I missing in this method workflow?

Tags: python

I'm learning how to use methods from a book and in this exercise I'm trying to find the max height of a projectile. I'm pretty sure I put the equation right into projectile.py, but every time I execute Exercise 1.py the result I get from `cball.getMaxY()` is always `"-0.0 meters."` What are some simple things I may have missed?

```
# projectile.py

"""projectile.py
Provides a simple class for modeling the 
flight of projectiles."""

from math import sin, cos, radians

class Projectile:

    """Simulates the flight of simple projectiles near the earth's
    surface, ignoring wind resistance. Tracking is done in two
    dimensions, height (y) and distance (x)."""

    def __init__(self, angle, velocity, height):
        """Create a projectile with given launch angle, initial
        velocity and height."""
        self.xpos = 0.0
        self.ypos = height
        theta = radians(angle)
        self.xvel = velocity * cos(theta)
        self.yvel = velocity * sin(theta)

        #Find time to reach projectile's maximum height
        self.th = self.yvel/9.8

    def update(self, time):
        """Update the state of this projectile to move it time seconds
        farther into its flight"""
        #Find max height
        self.maxypos = self.yvel - (9.8 * self.th)

        self.xpos = self.xpos + time * self.xvel
        yvel1 = self.yvel - 9.8 * time
        self.ypos = self.ypos + time * (self.yvel + yvel1) / 2.0
        self.yvel = yvel1

    def getY(self):
        "Returns the y position (height) of this projectile."
        return self.ypos

    def getX(self):
        "Returns the x position (distance) of this projectile."
        return self.xpos

    def getMaxY(self):
        "Returns the maximum height of the projectile."
        return self.maxypos
```

---

```
# Exercise 1.py
from projectile import Projectile

def getInputs():
    a = eval(input("Enter the launch angle (in degrees): "))
    v = eval(input("Enter the initial velocity (in meters/sec): "))
    h = eval(input("Enter the initial height (in meters): "))
    t = eval(input("Enter the time interval between position calculations: "))
    return a,v,h,t

def main():
    angle, vel, h0, time = getInputs()
    cball = Projectile(angle, vel, h0)
    while cball.getY() >= 0:
        cball.update(time)        
    print("\nDistance traveled: {0:0.1f} meters.".format(cball.getX()))
    print("\nMaximum height traveled: {0:0.1f} meters.".format(cball.getMaxY()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: where the code that uses this

Comment: Sorry, just added it.

Comment: Debugging tip. Add a print statement to update() and watch how the value of maxypos changes.

Comment: Thanks David. After debugging I found I did NOT go about the equation right :)

Answer (score 0):

This line doesn't make much sense:

```
self.maxypos = self.yvel - (9.8 * self.th)
```

Keep it simple; try something like:

```
self.maxypos = max(self.maxypos, self.ypos)
```

*after* you update `self.ypos`. You will also need to initialise `self.maxypos = self.ypos` in `__init__`.

You don't need all of those trivial getters; just access the attribute ([Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html)).